# How can I get the parent block using etherscan API?

Tags: etherscan, hash

I want to get the chain of blocks using etherscan API.
I can get any block by its number (eth_getBlockByNumber). I can get the latest block number as well (eth_blockNumber).
If I have the parent block number, I could do what I want. But in the current block, there is only a parent hash and no number. If it was possible to get the block by hash, it would be sufficient as well, but I can't see a proper API query.

Comment: I don't understand what's the question. If you are at block N then the parent is block N-1. The parent block number is implicit once the block number is available.

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely forgot that block numbers are just numbers and they go one by one.